# Cross Referencing dictionary Items to values in a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a dictionary with correct values that I want to be cross checked to the values found in a data frame. I want this operation to be in a function for use with other code later on.

```
import pandas as pd

d=[['Aland Islands','Cars','test@gmail.com']]
df=pd.DataFrame(d,columns=['country','industry','Email'])

errors={}

valid_dict={"country": ["Afghanistan", "Aland Islands"],"industry": ["Automotive", "Banking / Finance"]}
valid_dict={k:v for k, v in valid_dict.items() if k in df.columns.values}
```

This is just checking to makes sure all the keys and items in valid_dict are column names in the data frame. This works as expected no changes needed here just adding for context.

Here's the problem child of the code. I have tried to create a function but I am new with making functions. I want to compare the valid_dict key and items to the column names and values in the data frame and print a simple statement

```
def validate(df, valid_dict):
    {i:k for k, v in valid_dict.items() for i in v}
    for c in valid_dict:
        if df[c] in list(c):
              return 
        else:
              for c in valid_dict:
                  for i in df.index:
                      errors={ "row": i,                                    
                     "column": c,                                                 
                     "message": "This is an invalid entry, fill in "+c+ " accordingly" }  
                  return errors,df


print(validate(df, valid_dict))
```

I know this code is a mess I have tried all different kinds of things but I cant get the results I want.

desired output is:
`errors={ "row": 0, column": industry, "message": "This is an invalid entry, fill in "+industry+ " accordingly" }`

how to cross check a dictionary to a data frame to identify values not found in the set list of items in the dictionary?

For the scenario asked if a column has 10 values and 5 were errors I want it to print all 5 errors.

Comment: do you want to check all the columns? and create a resulting column in the DF if value in industry is valid or not?  or you want to print the error? I think making it part of the DF helps

Comment: The print statement is just there so I know the function works. I would like to keep it as a function so I can reference it and other functions all at once later with a for loop.

Comment: Yes just a single value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# inver the dictionary
d={i:k for k, v in valid_dict.items() for i in v}

# map industry and when its null, return an error message
# else the valid industry name
df['check']=df['industry'].mask(df['industry'].map(d).isna(), f"An invalid Value found in {col}")
df
```

```
country     industry    Email   check
0   Aland Islands   Cars    test@gmail.com  An invalid Value found in industry
```

FUNCTION:

```
def validate(col='industry', d=valid_dict):
    # column to validate
    # dictionary
    d={i:k for k, v in valid_dict.items() for i in v}
    
    # map column to dictionary 
    s=df[col].mask(df[col].map(d).isna(), "An invalid Value found in industry")
    
    # return the rows where the mapping had failed
    return s[s.map(d).isna()]

   
validate('industry')
```

```
0    An invalid Value found in industry
2    An invalid Value found in industry
Name: industry, dtype: object
```

Comment: I want to keep this in a function so I don’t direct reference a column name

Comment: ok. Does this work for you?

Comment: I think I mis interpreted what u meant but a single value to pass through the function, each column in the real def will have multiple values so calling just one as a key isn’t exactly what I’m looking for

Comment: for example, DF with 10 rows, 5 of them has invalid values, do you want to 1. print 5 invalid values (but then how you know which rows has invalid values). 2. stop when the first invalid value is encountered.  Share the expected output for this scenario in the question please.

Comment: I have updated the code again with more information on how to handle having multiple errors, I have a type error since i dont think the operation is correct.  @Naveed

Comment: @githubber, check the updated solution, it returns a consolidated series of the rows where mapping has failed for the specified column. Does it help?

Comment: iterating with a for-loop is an anti-pattern. There are number of functions available in Pandas and Numpy eliminating the need of For-loop. I attempted to suggest the solution in the same spirit. Hope it works for you